# Xcode new scenes and classes

Tags: ios, uiview, scenekit

I have my first class (which came default from Xcode)
From my first class I click a label which takes me to my new scene.

In this new scene I have a have two questions:

First questions: What kind of code should I write to be able to code on a new this new scene. I guess I have to start by referring/creating some kind of class, right?

Second questions: When writing my code in view controller.swift and referring to a class, where in Xcode can I change my scene's class name?

Comment: This is a bit vague... Also, why tag "swift" a question which seems to be about iOS + SceneKit? (just guessing here about your tech since you don't tell). You can improve your target audience and your chances to get answers with a better choice of tags and by giving more details and context in your question.

Comment: Well it is in swift you would create some code for this to work, right? in the viewcontroller.swift

Although, thanks for pointing that out and helping.

edit: I can see how hard it is to understand my question, I just have a hard time figuring out how to explain it better..

Comment: Swift is just the programming language you're using to access other tools, like UIKit, SceneKit, iOS frameworks, etc. So *no*, just Swift as a tag is not a good idea. Swift itself, the programming language, doesn't contain anything about animation, view controllers, scenes, etc.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I did not know that! Still learning as you can see.

Comment: I know you're learning. That's what I explain. :) You're welcome.

Comment: I made an assumption when closing this as a duplicate that you meant ViewController when you said scene. Are you using SceneKit or the standard ViewController?

Comment: Im using the standard view controller. And I have figured out to give it an id, so when I click my label on my first scene/viewcontroller, the user will jump to this next viewcontroller/scene. However, now I want to start coding a class on this new view controller, how would I do that?

Comment: class ViewController: UIViewController

That is what I write to start writing code for my first view controller/scene. 
What should I write to start writing code for my next scene? i gave it the id: "next". I tried writing class next: UIViewController